# fetch detail into the model view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.orderDetails = [
        {
            "id":"115584",
            "user_id":"78937",
            "your_sys_global":null,
            "created_at":"2017-12-08 05:03:20"
        },
        {
            "id":"115585",
            "user_id":"78936",
            "your_sys_global":"MicSamse",
            "created_at":"2017-12-08 05:03:21"
        },
        {
            "id":"115586",
            "user_id":"78938",
            "your_sys_global":null,
            "created_at":"2017-12-08 05:03:52"
        }
    ];

<div ng-repeat="user in profiles track by $index">
    <input
    type="text"
    name="your_sys_global_{{user.user_id}}"
    ng-model="orderDetails[user.user_id].your_sys_global"
    ng-change="saveOrder(user, orderDetails[user.user_id])"
    >
</div>
```

Details are not fetching into the textbox please guide why

Comment: Where is your `profiles` array?

Comment: If this is the exact code you're using, there's a missing comma at the end of `orderDetails`

Comment: Use `orderDetails` instead `profile`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `orderDetails[user.user_id]`, your `$scope.orderDetails` is an array an you need index to update a value in that array.

And why are you using `ng-change`, `ng-model` will itself update your `$scope.orderDetails` if set properly.

Add following method in your `$scope`

```
$scope.getUserOrder = function(user) {
  return $scope.orderDetails.filter(function(order) {
    return order.user_id === user.user_id;
  })[0]
}
```

and modify your markup to use this `method`

```
<div ng-repeat="user in profiles track by $index">
    <input
    type="text"
    name="your_sys_global_{{user.user_id}}"
    ng-model="getUserOrder(user).your_sys_global"
    >
</div>
```

There may be some typo mistakes, please don't mind.

Comment: why `user.user_id` can't by used as index? e.g. `ng-model="orderDetails[420].your_sys_global"`

Comment: Because `array` index are like `0.....n`. And they will not match with `user_id` in database.

Comment: he is pulling users from profiles and binds a model to that user with another array, so using a specific index makes sense, they don't have to come in any particular order (otherwise you might as well use `$index`)